# Mongoose cursor projection

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm having troubles with selectivly querying data within a db object. Here's my code, and it's really crucial for me to have a "end-of-query"-fire to determine when the query has ended.

```
var cursor = User.find({gender: 'male'}, 'username').cursor();

cursor.on('data', function(person) {
   console.log(person);
}

cursor.on('end', function() {
   console.log("done");
}
```

Comment: `cursor()` currently has some issues. Have you tried using `stream()` instead?

Comment: Yes, I have. But its prompting it's deprecated. Any ideas when it'll be fixied?